# Start Springboot without any Undertow Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, undertow

I have a project which mixes 2 dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-installed-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm getting a transitiv dependency for Undertow, which comes from

```
keycloak-installed-adapter
```

As far as I understood, Undertow is used internally within the KeyCloak libraries.

I don't want my Springboot Application to start with Undertow, nor I want that anything related with Undertow gets configured at Springboot level.

I can't find to completely exclude any Undertow configuration for Springboot. Does anyone have an idea?

### Update

I now have the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedUndertow.class})
public class SpringbootTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

But i'm getting following exception when starting my service:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/undertow/servlet/api/SessionPersistenceManager
```

Knowing that the EmbeddedUndertow Class lokks like:

```
   @Configuration
   @ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, Undertow.class, SslClientAuthMode.class })
   @ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
   public static class EmbeddedUndertow {

    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory undertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        return new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    }

}
```

How would you ignore this calss from the scanning?

Comment: I tried the following which didn't help:
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,pattern = "io\\.undertow\\..*"))

Comment: Have you tried to exclude that dependency ????????? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#how-to-use-dependency-exclusions

Comment: I actually don't want to completely exclude it, because KeyCloas uses it. What i'm looking for, is a way to start my Springboot App without auto-configuring things for Undertow.